# AppEngine Java8 app missing appengine-api-1.0

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My AppEngine Java8 app is missing appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.77.jar. I am getting this error on whatever servlet I call

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/memcache/ErrorHandler
```

The same code is running fine on another project. The only difference I could find is in the app.yaml where api_version is 'user_defined' instead of '1.0'

```
runtime: java8
api_version: user_defined
env: standard
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F1
inbound_services:
...
```

I am using eclipse tools to deploy.
Any ideas how to get fix the appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.77.jar problem or the api_version problem?

EDIT:
I am not using maven. here are the jars I have in WEB-INF/lib

```
firebase-admin-6.10.0.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.33.0.jar
json-20180813.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.28.jar
```

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml? I suspect you're deploying a .jar that's provided at runtime and this is causing a conflict. Also, java8 applications should use a [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) file rather than an app.yaml

Comment: Indeed, appengine-web.xml doesnt have anything about api_version. But the deployment tooI generate an app.yaml where api_version is 'user_defined'. I dont know where this is coming from. (please see my jars in the edit above)

Comment: Which deployment and build tools are you using?

Comment: Google cloud tools for eclipse https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/

Comment: I think you may have gone wrong somewhere during the initial configuration of your project, because when I follow the [steps to initiate a new project](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/creating-new-webapp), I get a pretty normal looking Java project with a appengine-web.xml file and not an app.yaml.

Comment: I though so. So, I created a new project both on eclipse and on google cloud, and deployed again. Same problem! While my previous 4 projects are working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now. Had to update Google Cloud SDK.
api_version is still user_defined, but the new Cloud SDK (274) is doing its magic somewhere else.